# Использование указателя на метод класса внутри другого метода этого же класса

Tags: c++, функции, классы, указатели, this

у меня возник вопрос: возможно ли  вызвать метод по указателю внутри другого метода? Все эти дела творятся внутри одного класса

Пример:

```
enum Method
{
    HK,
    WS,
    BB
};

class Example
{
    double pb_;

    double funLiquid (double parg) {...}
    double funHK (double parg) {...}
    double funWS (double parg) {...}
    double funBB (double parg) {...}
public:
    double calcSmth (double press, Method marg)
    {
         double (Example::*fun)(double);

         switch (marg)
         {
         case HK:
              fun = &Example::funHK;
              break;
         сase WS:
              fun = &Example::funWS;
              break;
         case BB:
              fun = &Example::funBB;
              break;
         }

         if ( press < pb_ )
         {
              return funLiquid(press);
         }
         else
         {
              return fun(press);
         }
    }
};
```

Подобная программа не компилируется, так как требует созданный объект класса (получается через this это тоже работать не будет?). 
Стоит ли в подобных ситуациях вообще использовать указатель на метод? 
Или стоит сделать так:

```
if (...) {...}
else
{
    switch (marg) 
    {
    case HK:
         return funHK(press);
    case WS:
         return funWS(press);
    case BB:
         return funBB(press);
    }
}
```

Comment: второй вариант лучше, более читаемо и в данном случае нет явной нужды использовать указатели на функции-члены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы скомпилировать -

```
return (this->*fun)(press);
```

Что лучше? откровенно говоря, ощущение XY-проблемы. Всегда настороженно отношусь к большим `switch` для выбора функциональности. А если появится еще одна функция?...